# Rotate one object around another in Java

Tags: java, rotation

**

---

**Goooglers** remember to use tx.setToRotation(Math.toRadians(angle)); when using Li's method.

**

I'm making a cell-based game in which every "organism" consists of multiple 10x10 pixel sqaures(cells), these cells must be connected to a "main cell" otherwise they are removed. the main cell holds a int which represents it's angle(0-360.), when the main cell rotates it has to align all of the connected cells with it. example bellow

[image: Cells rotated 0 degrees]
[image: Cells rotated 120 degrees]

I can already draw them on this angle, I just need the functions getX() and getY() of Cell to return a modified X/Y based off the main cell's rotation.

**Given the main cells angle(int angle), the offset of given Cell(int xMod, int yMod) and current location (int x, int y) can you make a getter and setter for Cell which returns a X and Y modified to suit the rotation of the main Cell(owner)?**

Comment: Not sure what you are asking with "modified X/Y based off the main cell's rotation." Do you mean a relative (x,y) against the coord plane in which the main cell is the origin, and that plane is rotated?

Comment: @StoneBird by "Modified X/Y" I mean a X/Y which is effected by the rotation of the main cell, say two cells were next to eachother and one rotates, the other cell would be draw slightly higher/lower and slightly more to the right/left

Comment: So you want the (x,y) when the main cell rotates again, given the parameters before such rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the [AffineTransform](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html) class, which provides easy to use methods for various tranformations, including rotation. Then construct a [Point2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.html) using your (x, y) values and apply the AffineTransform to get a new Point2D that is rotated. This is nice because its usage is very similar to what you're currently using to rotate the graphics context.

```
AffineTransform tx = new AffineTransform();
tx.rotate(...);

Point2D point = new Point2D.Double(x, y);
Point2D rotated = new Point2D.Double();
tx.transform(point, rotated);
```

Bonus: you can use the transform for both the rendering and calculations! You can apply the AffineTransform on a Graphics2D object to cut down on similar/duplicate code.

```
Graphics2D g = ...
g.transform(tx);
```

Comment: Thank you, it will need some tweeking... http://puu.sh/58zeR.png

http://puu.sh/58zgK.png